# Updating a Part of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to know if it is possible to update a small part of string in MySQL. For example, you have 100 pages stored in MySQL table. In each page there is a link which labeled at "2010 Updates". You want to change the Label to "2011 Updates". Can we do that using MySQL Update statement???

Thank you so much

Comment: Post your Database structure.  Post some sample data.  Then we could have a better idea on how to write that update statement if that's what needs to be done.

Comment: Where do you want to update it and what application/language are you using? I believe you cannot achieve this by SQL query. You need to do it in php/ruby/asp/c# ? what?

Comment: If you like my answer, would you click the green checkmark under the the arrows to the left of the answer.  It marks my answer as correct, and closes the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this video http://www.sebastiansulinski.co.uk/tutorials/play/261
I would just do a select statement, and looping through it, running a regex on each row, then updating said row; but the video gives you another option.